# Why is cmake Visual Studio 2013 project not finding headers?

Tags: cmake

I am using to build my project for Visual Studio 2013. It uses CUDA.
In order to add the headers to the project's path I am using `cuda_include_directories()`, however, VS intelliSense is not recognizing it. Why is that?

I can compile and I know this is not a big problem but it bugs me that intelliSense is marking the include red-underlined.

Any idea?

Comment: As a workaround for what it bugs you, does it help to use the console to build your application instead of VS IDE so your red-underline bugness go away?

Comment: Could you please add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because I think it has to be `include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})` not `cuda_include_directories()`. The [`CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( path0 path1 ... )` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html) says "Sets the directories that should be passed to nvcc (e.g. nvcc -Ipath0 -Ipath1 ... ). These paths usually contain other .cu files."